# Toggle between pool of classes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to use vanilla JavaScript or jQuery to toggle between two classes is a question, that has been asked and answered many times on stackoverflow and other websites.

What I haven't found though is a solution to use the onclick event to toggle between a pool of classes.

What I want to achive is this:

I have a body element with the class "yellow". 
When clicking a button, I want this class removed from the body and replaced with the class "green". Clicking the button again should change the class to "red" and next time to "blue" and finally back to "yellow" and so on.

Any ideas are much appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: Can you supply and example? or a fiddle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple answer, you can modify it so you push or pop more classes into the array and so on.

```js
var classes = ["yellow", "green", "red"];

var button = $("#changeColor");
var count = 1;
button.on("click", function(){
  $("#foo").removeClass();
  $("#foo").addClass(classes[count]);
  count++;
  if(count > 2){
   count = 0;
  }
});
```

```css
.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="foo" style="width: 200px; height: 50px;" class="yellow">
  FOO
</div>

<button id="changeColor">CHANGE</button>
```

Comment: I found this answer to be the most correct one because it actually changes the class instead of just adding inline css to the body element. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the fiddle to fit my needs but the problem is that toggling the classes removes ALL previous classes, not just the colour classes. 
Any idea how to keep all other classes and only replace the colour ones?
Have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/nrs3snou/13/

Comment: @JaschaGoltermann just remove the previous class using something like count-1 and a special case if the count is at 0. I'll post a fiddle when I get home if you don't solve it by then.

Comment: Thanks, Franjo! I have updated the fiddle with another solution that only removes the class if it matches one of the colour names but I'm sure you have a more elegant way. Anyway, here is what I came up with: https://jsfiddle.net/nrs3snou/21/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at below snippet. Please note, in pool all colors should be unique otherwise you have to create an extra variable to track the index of applied color.

```js
var pool = ['yellow', 'green', 'red', 'blue']
var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
body.style.backgroundColor = 'yellow';
function changeColor() {
  var bodyColor = body.style.backgroundColor;
  var appliedIndex = pool.indexOf(bodyColor);
  if (appliedIndex === pool.length - 1) {
    body.style.backgroundColor = pool[0];
  } else {
    body.style.backgroundColor = pool[appliedIndex + 1];
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="change" onClick="changeColor()">Change</button>
```